# Formal synonym of "As I mentioned before"

Tags: grammar, synonyms

I have a question about a synonym of this sentence "As I mentioned before". The only synonym that I know is "As I said before", but it's informal because I searched about it on Internet, but I can't find more information to resolve my problem.

Comment: What is it you are "mentioning"? Depending on what you were saying you could use: "As I explained previously." or "As I described previously."

Comment: Oh thanks Steve! I'll use these synonyms in a future interview.

Comment: If the thing you are bringing back up was only very briefly mentioned, or not properly explained before, you could also say "As I [alluded](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/allude) to previously".

Comment: It's not clear what is wrong with "as I mentioned before". It is also not clear to me why you think "As I said before" is informal, it seems quite neutral to me. You don't clearly ask a question or specify a problem to solve.